# Get data from a host out of the `--limit` option

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook (`playbook.yaml`)

```yaml
- hosts: myfirsthost[0]
  tasks:
    - name: Get a token
      slurp:
        src: /var/mytoken
      register: tokenFile

- hosts: myotherhosts
  vars:
    fileToken: "{{ hostvars[groups['myfirsthost'][0]]['tokenFile']['content'] | b64decode | replace('\n', '') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
    msg: The token {{fileToken}}
```

When I run it for all hosts, it works fine.

But when I run it against a single host contained in the group `myotherhosts` (not in group `myfirsthosts`)

```
ansible playbook.yaml --limit thesinglehost
```

It doesn't play the first task, then the variable can not be initialized, and that is expected.

Do you have any idea how I can force the task "Get a token" for all hosts, even if they are not in `myfirsthost`?

Comment: Is thesinglehost a filename or the hostname ?

Comment: thesinglehost is the hostname

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-i 'host,'` then ?

Comment: This is an example task, in fact, it is more complicated. I have to get data from myfirsthost, I have not to play other tasks to myfisthost, only on thesinglehost

Comment: As pointed by @Marged, you need to specify a file or a list for `-i`. You can check how that is going to be interpreted with something like `ansile-inventory --list -i 'thesinglehost,'` and compare with `ansible-inventory --list -i thesinglehost`.

Comment: OK, understood, the problem is not the syntax of -i , I made a mistake in the question. The right syntax is ``` ansible-playbook  --limit thesinglehost playbook.yaml ``` The question is still the same, how to force the task "Get a token" for thesinglehost, even if it is not in myfirsthost group?

Comment: If you made a mistake in the question then go ahead and fix it. People won't know what you want if you don't state it clearly in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem

When you use `--limit` in your `ansible-playbook` command, you cannot play **any** tasks on hosts out of this limit. This includes gathering facts (i.e. play the `setup` module automatically or explicitly) and `set_fact` (i.e. create/update a fact manually for the host). With ansible default settings (memory facts cache), you will not be able to query any `hostvars` on those hosts inside your playbook because there are no keys for their `inventory_hostname` in that dict.

## Facts cache to the rescue

A solution is to enable a non ephemeral facts cache in `ansible.cfg`. The default cache goes to memory and dies at the end of the playbook.

### Enable the cache

As a start, you can enable and store the cache in json files on disk with the following settings in `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /path/to/cache/folder
```

For more info about this feature and all the possible cache backends, you can look at the comments for the relevant parameters in the [default `ansible.cfg` file](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/ansible.cfg) and check the [cache plugin documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html)

### Populate the cache

Once you have a non ephemeral cache, you can gather facts and `set_fact` for all relevant hosts. If you only need facts queried from the host, you can easily do this with an ad-hoc command:

```
ansible -i your/inventory my_hosts -m setup
```

In your case, it is a bit more complicated, as you want to push to the cache the result of a task. You will need to create a first playbook that you will run on all hosts you need to use later. I'll call it `init_facts_and_tokens.yml`:

```yaml
---
- name: Gather hosts facts and initialize tokens
  hosts: my_hosts
  # You can uncomment the line below to be explicit but this is on by default
  # gather_facts: true

  tasks:
    - name: Slurp token file token
      slurp:
        src: /var/mytoken
      register: token_file

    - name: Register token in facts cache
      set_fact:
        token: "{{ token_file.content | b64decode | replace('\n', '') }}"
```

and your run it on all hosts with

```
ansible-playbook -i your/inventory init_facts_and_tokens.yml
```

### Use the cache

Now that the cache is populated, you can play your other playbook, with a limit or not, and call `hostvars` for hosts out of the play/limit. If their facts have been correctly cached, you will get the values queried during the last facts gathering or `set_fact`

In such a scenario, you can probably disable facts gathering on all your plays to save some execution time on your final playbook. And if for any reason (e.g. changing a network interface, adding an lvm volume.....) you need to refresh the facts during the play, you can simply run the [`setup` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html). For any other fact not queried from you host, any use of `set_fact` for the given variable will create/refresh its value

```yaml
---
- name: Do the jobs with cache facts
  hosts: my_hosts
  gather_facts: false
 
  vars:
    # We will use toker from first server in group,
    # even if out of the limit
    this_play_token: "{{ hostvars[groups['my_hosts'][0]].token }}"
  
  tasks:
    - name: Show token
      debug:
        msg: "The token for this play is {{ this_play_token }}"

    # Examples to illustrate above explanations
    - name: This task can use cache
      debug:
        msg: "OS of somehost.com is: {{ hostvars['somehost.com'].ansible_os_familly }}"

    - name: This task would change target, possibly obsoleting gathered facts
      debug:
        msg: "Warning I might change system facts !"

    - name: Refresh facts cache
      setup:

    - name: Back to normal activity
      debug:
        msg: "I use latest gathered facts from cache"
    
    - name: This would refresh the cached token for current host
      set_fact:
        token: "Not so valid token"
```

You can now launch this second playbook with a limit or not. It will still be able to read facts (queried or user set) for any host even out of the play

```
# run on all hosts
ansible-playbook -i your/inventory final_playbook.yml

# run only on third host of my_hosts group
ansible-playbook -i your/inventory --limit my_host[2] final_playbook.yml
```